# MongoDB Compass Exporting Collection with Unwanted Metadata

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

When exporting a collection using MongoDB Compass (regardless of query) to JSON, the output now includes metadata ($oid, $numberInt, $numberDouble). I've exported several collections in the past couple of weeks without issue but now every export includes metadata which is affecting how the JSON is being parsed in external software.

I've tried updating to the latest version of MongoDB (4.0.10) & MongoDB Compass (1.18.0) both Community Edition, with no resolution.

Expected Output: {"_id":"unique_id"},"transaction_id":"1059833"},"transaction_amount":"2000"}}

Actual Output: {"_id":{"$oid":"unique_id"},"transaction_id":{"$numberInt":"1059833"},"transaction_amount":{"$numberInt":"2000"}}

Comment: Is the actual output correct? Your missing a closing `}` Can you give us a sample of the data from the db please by [edit]ing your question

Comment: The actual output data is incorrect. The key-value pair should be {transaction_id: 1059833} but for some reason the export is assigning the keys to objects with their own key-value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code if you are using mongo-java-driver:

```
Use new JsonWriterSettings(JsonMode.SHELL).

Document doc = new Document("startDate", new Document("$gt", first).append("$lt", second)); 
System.out.println(doc.toJson(new JsonWriterSettings(JsonMode.SHELL)));
```

More details on page: 
https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.7/bson/extended-json/